# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, if print is used in attributes

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

We are using Underscore 1.8.3 as template engine.

Here is code giving error:

```
<script>
        {{  if(rc.u_type==1){ t_checked="checked"; } }}                 
</script>
<label><input type="radio" name="u_type" value="2" {{ print(t_checked) }} > User </label>
```

Here printing `t_checked` variable in input tag attribute give error `Unexpected Identifier`.

However, if we use the same `{{ print(t_checked) }}` anywhere else it is OK.

How can we set attribute based on value in template data as mentioned?

Comment: Why is there a `<script>` tag inside your underscore template?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not able to reproduce the problem from my end with your provided sample, I would just point out how it could be totally avoided to declare a new variable within the template.

Just using `{{ if(rc.u_type==1){ }}checked="checked"{{ } }}` is enough.

```js
var html = '<label><input type="radio" name="u_type" value="2" {{ if(rc.u_type==1){ }}checked="checked"{{ } }}> User </label>';

var template = _.template(html, {
  evaluate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
});

console.log(template({
  rc: {
    u_type: 1
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```